# New Relic Configuration in .Net 6

Tags: rest, configuration, .net-6.0, newrelic

I am working on a .net 6 Rest API project and new to New Relic,

so far what I did is created an account and got the license key from that, installed the nuGet package NewRelic.Agent.Api and add the key in app-settings file, after that I add the line of code in program.cs

`builder.Services.AddNewRelic(builder.Configuration["NewRelic:LicenseKey"]);`

but getting error that *IServiceColection does not contain a definition for AddNewRelic.*

Am I missing something? any package which could support this?

I am looking forward for the response.